# Why am I seeing this image instead of my static firebase website?

Tags: firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

I expecting see my firebase website but instead of the web app, I seeing this image. I think I followed the [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/) docs.
[image]

Here's my firebase.json:

```
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After running **firebase deploy**, it says:

> Deploy complete!

What did I miss? :(

Thanks, 
Adi

Answer (score 2):

This is infact your website. When you run `Firebase init` it prepopulates the public folder (which you selected to be your dist directory) with the sample site you are seeing. You must place all of your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into the dist directory and the run `firebase deploy --only hosting`

Comment: What is the contents of your `dist` directory? That is what will be deployed to firebase based on your configuration file